# iCloud and Core Data not working - URLForUbiquityContainerIndentifier is nil

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, icloud

I am not that familiar with iCloud integration. I read numerous bad reports about the integration in iOS 5 and 6. But now I guess it's better in iOS 7 so I decided to add it in one of the new apps I'm working on.

From what I read and saw in the WWDC 2013 CoreData/iCloud video I thought it was as simple as flipping on iCloud in Xcode and configuring the `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey` value to something unique in the `addPersistentStore` call, to get started. But each time I run the app, in the simulator or on a physical iPhone, the console output shows the iCloud setup failed due to `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier` returning `nil`.

I am using Xcode 6 beta and the iOS 8 beta 2 SDK. I've made sure iCloud is signed in and otherwise functioning on the simulator and physical devices. I've also made sure that the "Documents/Data" switch is on under iCloud setting and the app IS appearing here. I've also browsed to the simulator application directory and I see the SQLite file in the normal documents directory and in an iCloud directory.

Is there something really simple I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the developer agreements allows to say, but at the time of writing this, it is still beta and most probably is a bug in xcode 6. There may be a few threads on the developer forum on that exact same subject. Search for 'URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier' and you may find more information.

**Try beta 4.** My iCloud code is now working.

Answer (score 1):

There is bug in Xcode 6 beta version , i am using Xcode6 beta 5 and facing same problem.

I changed key com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers to com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers" (ubiquity, not icloud). Then add an item to this as "iCloud.$(CFBundleIdentifier)".  In "Capabilities" tab Xcode will show error in red mark but don't fix it , leave as it is.

If solved my problem and i am getting Url now.

Comment: I'm not sure if this the bug you are finding, but if I tap on "use default container" in Capabilities with Xcode6 (not beta!) this consistently crashes Xcode.

Comment: For some reason it still returns nil for me, but i updated the entitlements and info.plist for iCloud Drive, have any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: in Xcode 6 gm seed also i followed same steps and it worked. In Xcode 6 i tried calling     NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]; and it returned me the url. Two basic things 1. We should always check in device 2.Make sure you login to iCloud in settings app

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention configuring your app ID for iCloud access and updating your provisioning profile, so that's probably the problem. The device needs to know that your app is allowed to talk to iCloud, and it does that based on the provisioning profile. You'll need to go to the iOS developer site and:

1. Update the app ID to add the iCloud capability
2. Regenerate the provisioning profile so that it includes the new capability
3. Download a new copy of the profile and make sure that you're using it in testing (it's best to delete the old copy first just to be sure).

Comment: I did the first two steps after I turned the iCloud switch on but I didn't do the 3rd step. I just tried it but it didn't fix anything still the same error.

Comment: I manually downloaded the provisioning profile, I let Xcode regenerate it and nothing changed. I've been trying this with iOS 8 beta 2, so I tried it by building on iOS 7. It gave a slightly different log output but basically the same error that it was returning NULL when trying to find the Ubiquity URL. I tried this on an old app I had developed just to see if it was something with the App ID or the Xcode project itself - Same thing. I'm wondering if it's a bug either with the SDK, Xcode 6, Yosemite Beta or a combination. So next I'm going to try to do it on a Mavericks installation and see.